# How to list a property of firebase object as an array?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a firebase databse with the following structure:

[image: list of my database structure]

Each one of those random UIDs have `creator` and `roomName`. I am trying to display all roomName in an array, like `["Holy Robert Louis Stevenson", "Holy Sardine", "Holy Gunpowder"]`, but it is always displayed as `[Object, Object, Object]`

Here is my code:

```
const dbRef = firebase.initializeApp(config).database().ref().child('rooms');
...
  componentDidMount(){
    dbRef.on('value', snap => {
      console.log(snap.val());
      console.log('firebaseHolyArray: ', Object.values(snap.val()));
    });
  }
```

I hav tried `console.log('firebaseHolyArray: ', Object.values(snap.val())["roomName"]);` but it displays undefined. How can I display the values of `roomName` in array format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [forEach() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach), which will produce a properly ordered list from Firebase data:

```
dbRef.on('value', snap =>  {
   var data = [];
   snap.forEach(ss => {
      data.push(ss.child('name').val());
   });
   console.log(data);
});
```

There's no need to do multiple iterations with Object.values() or using underscore, both of which will likely produce out of order data and other complications here.

Also, ideally you should get into the habit of using the [recommended practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) for working with lists, such as `child_added`.

Comment: What's the best practice for dealing with the Firebase object keys? I come from Backbone where id is usually a property of the object model data, (currently use a lot of RiotJS). To me it makes a lot of sense to have the firebase key/ref duplicated as a property of the data so that when I convert to the array to do something like loop through and print stuff, each model has convenient id prop associated with it that I can use as a reference when I have to update that model.

`Le829fn9283749w48: { id: "Le829fn9283749w48", msg: "Hello" }`

Yes? No?

Comment: Sure, this is fine. There's really no "best" here. You can pass around the snapshots (which contain the data and the key and lots of other useful things), pass around the data only, pass around data with key, pass data with key duplicated within, and others.

Comment: Thanks @Kato. Programming solo I'm always second guessing some of the habits I've picked up. It works... but maybe I'm missing something obvious to others? That sort of thinking kills me, and why getting other opinions on Stack is so helpful. Much appreciated. ;-D

Answer (score 3):

I think `snap.val()` is returning something like this:

```
{
  "-KeoiS8luCsuKhzc_Eut": { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Robert Louis Stevenson" },
  "-Keol-2Si05dmkmuac8l": { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Sardine" },
  "-KeooOxSoYNdNk6g5DMw": { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Gunpowder" }
}
```

We can use `Object.values(snap.val())` to transform it into an array of objects, like this:

```
[
  { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Robert Louis Stevenson" },
  { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Sardine" },
  { "creator": "Robin", "roomName": "Holy Gunpowder" }
]
```

Then, we want to extract the room name from each object. The array `map` method would be helpful in this situation to transform the objects into what we want. In the end, I think it should look something like this:

```
var rooms = Object.values(snap.val()).map(function(obj) {
  return obj.roomName;
});
console.log('firebaseHolyArray: ', rooms);
```

This will take the array of objects, and pass each one into our function. In that function, you can return what part of the object you want to end up with...In this case, the `roomName`. You will be left with an array of these, which you can easily print out.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: snap.val(...).map is not a function`. I think I see where you are going with this, though.

Comment: @ikicha may have it slightly more right with this: `Object.values(snap.val()).map`...Maybe try that instead?

Comment: I assumed `snap.val()` was returning an array, but if it is returning as an object, then my approach wouldn't work. `Object.values` will convert it to an array, which then allows `map` to do it's magic.

Comment: @Iggy, I've updated the answer based on these assumptions. I hope you find it helpful!

Comment: A better solution here would be to use snap.forEach() and iterate the elements once, instead of doing Object.values() (an iteration) and Object.map() (another iteration). Additionally, the values will be in the correct order from the database if forEach() is used rather than snap.val().

Comment: Nice, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 1):

Object.values() returns Object[].

So, it doesn't cotain "roomName" attribute.

I think you use `map` for pluck.

Here is code

```
console.log('firebaseHolyArray: ', Object.values(snap.val()).map((v) => v.roomName);
```

If you use underscore, you can also use underscore.pluck.

```
console.log('firebaseHolyArray: ', _.pluck(Object.values(snap.val()), "roomName"));
```

Refer to http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Answer (score 1):

```
export const mapObjectToArray = (obj: any) => {
    const mappedDatas = [];
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            mappedDatas.push({ ...obj[key], id: key });
        }
    }
    return mappedDatas;
};
```

Here a function that I use to convert a Firebase object in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [];
      const keys=Object.keys(rooms);
      const values=Object.values(rooms);
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       const temp={
          key:keys[i],...values[i];
        }
        data.push(temp);
      }
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32411902)