# I would like help changing a Firebase Database object to an Array, in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to query the Realtime Database of Firebase using Angular-Fire 2 to retrieve a specific set of entries.

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "date" : "2017-10-16T00:00:00.000",
    "food" : "Pizza",
    "sport" : "Soccer"
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-10-15T00:00:00.000",
    "food" : "Ceviche",
    "sport" : "Basketball"
  }, {
    "date" : "2017-10-14T00:00:00.000",
    "food" : "Fruits",
    "sport" : "Cricket"
  } ]

  }
```

I would like to return only "Food" and its values for the first 20 entries.

After that is done, I would like to take those entries and add them to an Array.

I am stumped. I can't figure how to pull back only the "Food" entries, and add only those values to the array. This is what i have so far. This is all i generally need.

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

this.items = db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToFirst(20)).valueChanges();

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

I will like to be able to Interpolate that Array and also be able to use that array in Functions.

Comment: Does "/items/food" not work?

Comment: I would still need to know how to push to an Array .

Comment: that works but regardless if i use snapshotChanges() and get an array returned I still can go into the HTML and do something like {{Array[1]}} .

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage to push them into an array in FireStore, unless there are significant other differences in firebase, this should also work with your setup. At least it could provide a point to start with.

```js
foodlist: Array<any> = [];

  customFunction() {
    this.afs.collection<IItem>(`items`, ref => ref.limit(20)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(foo => {
      return foo.map(bar => {
        const obj = bar.payload.doc.data() as IItem;
        const food = obj.food;
        return { food };
      });
    })).subscribe(a => {
      this.foodlist.push(a);
    });
    console.log(this.foodlist);
  }
}
export interface IItem {
  date: string;
  food: string;
  sport: string;
}
```

I edited to a better snippet that only returns food.

For firebase, the array push method should be something close to this:

```
db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToFirst(20)).valueChanges().subscribe(a => {array.push(food, a.food)}) // if you can't use a.food, use {array.push(a)}
```

Comment: Syntax is different. How would i change " this.afs.collection " ?

Comment: Hi, @NovaNova you should go with this.items = this.db(`/items`, ref => { your query params});
then build your array from the items snapshot if I remember correctly. Back in the day, firebase didn't have valuechanges() that's why I thought it may be similar. 
Please check this: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/simple-firebase-pagination-with-angularfire2/
and this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md 
And this: https://medium.com/@justintulk/how-to-query-arrays-of-data-in-firebase-aa28a90181ba

Comment: I figured that snapshotChanges() returns an Array. odd thing about that is i cant get any of the values on client side. Like " <p> {{Array[2]}}</p> comes back blank.

Comment: @NovaNova did you try to unwrap the array with json pipe first? <p> {{array | json }} </p> 
I suspect you need to trim the array first because if I remember correctly firebase returns an array like this: [{ 0: { field: value, field2: value2 }, 1: {field: value, field2: value2}}]

Comment: I'm working on getting this done. Can't seem to get anywhere though.

Comment: Where do i place your code ? inside of ngOnInit {     } ?

Comment: @NovaNova You need to place the code in the template. (your html file) once you have the array set in your TS file, you can unwrap it as a json to see how it appears by using json pipe. Documentation is very solid: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe
After you make sure you have trimmed and shaped your array to a format where you can repeat with ng-for, or unwrap single objects from it, then you will be able to display objects and their properties. 

This question provides a good guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722703/how-to-list-a-property-of-firebase-object-as-an-array

Comment: With snapshotChanges() , i get back an array of objects, like this [{..object1..} , {..object2..}]. If i use Object.values(), i get back the objects, and not the contents of them. I want the "Content Inside" the objects.

Comment: @NovaNova can you add arrays from both scenarios to your question? If you are receiving objects, you should be able to use a push method like mentioned in the question I provided above: 
`dbRef.on('value', snap =>  {
   var data = [];
   snap.forEach(ss => {
      data.push(ss.child('name').val());
   });
   console.log(data);
});`
What this does is: it receives the array first from firebase in its format, then it runs a loop and extracts the field called "name" and its value and pushes it into an array. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: so 'ss' is ambiguous ? Will the data be returned like an array with a json object  or will it be just an array with the values ? Also is 'value' ambiguous ?

Comment: @NovaNova "ss" is just a temporary variable that replaces the object. When you are running the forEach loop, ss represents the object. The arrow function acts as "then". So, you run a loop (`forEach`), you get the object (`ss`) then (arrow function `=>`) you push the each object's certain field's value to an array (field: `'name'`, value is extracted by `'val()'` from the field.) For a better solution that's applicable to TS you could use: `db.list('/items', ref => ref.limitToFirst(20)).valueChanges().subscribe(a => {array.push(food, a.food)}) // if you can't use a.food, use {array.push(a)}`

Comment: Thanks, You are the MAN.! I probably should have mentioned TS. I totally get the part where i may not be able to use a.food . I was having that issue yesterday. Where the console won't compile and the error was No value/method on such and such ..... so in the HTML, i could now just call {{a[1]}} ?

Comment: @NovaNova cool :) I'm glad it's resolved. I had those sorts of trouble when I started as well, SO helped a whole lot to understand how it all worked. I don't know your array so I can't really guess if you can call single object from it or not, but you can surely display your array as `{{array.json}}` first to see how you need to shape it. But if everything is as I assume it is, you should be able to call `{{array[1].food}}` just fine.